# Deleting oldest files to free space as needed on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I have a cron job that writes logs to `/tmp`. I want to automatically delete the oldest files when the free space in the disk becomes less than 1GB.

I'm trying to do `df -ah /tmp`, then take the 2nd line, use `cut` to get the `avail` column. Then in a `for` loop, keep deleting the files older than n days with `-mtime` until there's enough free space.

I probably want to set this up as a cron job that runs daily as well.

Comment: I'm trying to do `df -ah /tmp`, then take the 2nd line, use `cut` to get the avail column. Then in a for loop, keep deleting the files older than n days with -mtime. Until there's enough free space.

Comment: You should put that in your question, you can [edit] it. So you have a concept and tried to make a script that uses it, right? Include that script too.

Comment: Apart from bash scripting, are you sure this will be enough? For instance, currently I have 96K in my `/tmp`, which is much smaller than 1G, the remaining free space. It is probably a better idea to run `apt-get autoremove && apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean` to regain some free space.

Comment: If you're running Debian or a derivative of it, you may consider using `tmpreaper`: it does precisely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a find -mtime, do an ls -t, for example:

```
DIR=/tmp
FREESPACE=1000000
find $DIR -type f | xargs ls -1rt | while read f ; do
  if [ `df --output=avail $DIR | tail -1` -ge $FREESPACE ] ; then
    break
  fi
  # rm -f $f
done
```

Uncomment the `rm -f $f` to have it actually work...

However, I typically would do things a little differently.  I'd put my cron logs in /var/log and let something like logrotate handle managing disk space.  Or as another alternative, I'd put the logs into a separate subdirectory such as /tmp/mycronjob/*, and then keep a fixed number of days of log files.  It's not as flexible as monitoring disk space, but it's also a straight forward `find /tmp/mycronjob -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;` and more predictable.

Comment: I think the rm -f should be after the conditional. Otherwise it will always delete at least 1 directory even if there's enough available space.

Comment: @MorganChristiansson true.

Comment: Parsing `ls` [is flawed in general](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).